# switch не переключает страницу selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, тестирование

Страница настроек открывается в браузере, делаю switch и ожидаю переход на прошлую страницу. Но переход не осуществляется.

```
window_before = self.driver.window_handles[0]
settings = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@href='/settings']")
settings.click()
self.driver.switch_to.window(window_before)
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй это `driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")`